# Preventing Netsuite picking up new tickets

Tags: netsuite

We've recently moved off Netsuite as our main CRM, and I've been tasked with disabling it. We still have historic tickets in there that need closing, but I want to disable Netsuite from picking up any new tickets from our support mailbox.

I'm new in this role and have little Netsuite experience. Can anyone tell me how to prevent Netsuite from picking up new support tickets, while allowing us to work on closing the existing tickets? Our new CRM is picking up the new tickets.

I've been googling, but can't find out how to do this. I'm very new to Netsuite, and as soon as I've worked out how to perform the basic admin functions, we're moving away from it. I'm cautious that I need to still allow open tickets to be processed and worked on, so can't just cancel everything down.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try asking at https://netsuiteprofessionals.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cases in Netsuite are created either through a form or email capture via forwarding a company address to a Netsuite address.

> The Email Case Capture feature at Setup > Company > Enable Features > CRM > Support automatically
>   converts customer support messages your company receives into organized cases in NetSuite.
>   Depending on the specific requirements of your business, you can use case capture to create a simple
>   catch-all support address, or you can create a more sophisticated customer support model by using
>   Case Profiles.

From: https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/netsuitecs_gs/NSSMG/NSSMG.pdf

> Case capture works by forwarding your company’s support email address to a NetSuite-generated
>   address. You will need to make a note of this when setting up forwarding on your mail server.

Logic dictates that removing/unchecking case capture in this setting will turn off case creation. You may also need to turn off the case forwarding/capture user setup in your exchange, depending on how it was originally setup.

This won't erase existing cases, but it will stop new cases from being created.

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a forwarder on our support address, forwarding to a unique looking Netsuite address. I've disabled the forward, and also unchecked the Email Case Capture box. This allows us to continue working on already created cases, whilst preventing Netsuite from creating new cases. Problem solved, thanks again Jdg50!